# Is there a name for the feature of an IDE that allows you to execute code in the command line during debugging?

Tags: python, c++, matlab, ide

For example, in MATLAB you can set a breakpoints, execute up to the breakpoint, and then try things out in the command window using the variables in the current scope at that point in the program. It is much easier and faster to iron out bugs this way.

Is there a name given to this feature of an IDE? What allows this in an IDE? Are there other IDEs and/or programming languages that feature this?

Comment: Setting breakpoint at specific lines of code, and run in debug mode? That's common for any decent modern IDE. Also I have no clue what this has to do with the command line??

Comment: I have debugged before using visual studio programming in C++. While debugging, I could view the values that had been assigned to variables and associated addresses up to that point, but I could not try potential edits or additions to the code without continuing, recompiling, and rerunning. That takes a stupid amount of time. MATLAB offers such a sandbox to play in when debugging through its "command window". Is this trait unique to MATLAB?

Answer (score -2):

If you have to use command line, gdb and breakpoint meet your requirement.

If you can use UI, vscode is a good option for many languages: https://code.visualstudio.com/

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I will look into this.

Comment: For others: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/cpp/cpp-debug#_expression-evaluation
At least here, this feature of the debugger is referred to as "expression evaluation".